# Extracting all CSS classes and ID's in a given HTML block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I have a textarea where I paste a block of HTML code. When I hit submit, I want to extract all CSS classes and ID's from that block and throw them into an array.

So far I have the submit working as well as the regular expression, but i don't know how to filter through the whole block and extract all instances where text matches my regular expression.

index.html

```
<body>
    <textarea id="codeInput"></textarea>
    <button id="submitCode">submit</button>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

function.js

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitCode').click(function() {
        var codeInput = $('textarea#codeInput').val();
        console.log(codeInput);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#submitCode').click(function() {
    var codeInput = $('textarea#codeInput').val();
    var codeHTML = $('<div>', { html: codeInput }); // Parse the input as HTML
    var allIds = [];
    var allClasses = [];
    codeHTML.find('[id]').each(function() {
        allIds.push(this.id);
    });
    codeHTML.find('[class]').each(function() {
        allClasses = allClasses.concat(this.className.split(' '));
    });
    console.log("IDs: " + allIds.join(', '));
    console.log("Classes: " + allClasses.join(', '));
});
```

Comment: For some reason, this does not work, it doesn't print any ID's or classes to console when I paste HTML code into the textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/1525/

Comment: Fixed a bunch of capitalization errors. Also, `concat` doesn't modify the array like `push` does, so need to assign the result (I could also use `splice`).

Answer (score 0):

Make your function.js something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitCode').click(function() {
        var codeInput = $('textarea#codeInput').val();
        var $input = $(codeInput);
        var attrs: {
            'class': [],
            'id': []
        };
        $input.find('*').each(function() {
            attrs.class.push($(this).attr('class'));
            attrs.id.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        attrs.class.push($input.attr('class'));
        attrs.id.push($input.attr('id'));
    });
});
```

That goes through each element in the input code, and removes their `class` and `id` attributes, by first going through all the children of the container element in the input, and then afterwards doing the same for the container element in the input.

Comment: OP doesn't want to remove class and id, they want to store in array.

Comment: `.children` only gets immediate children, not all descendants.

Comment: err I'm not looking to remove anything, just looking to put all classes and ID's in a block of HTML into an array. Thanks though.

Comment: `$(codeInput)` won't work if `codeInput` doesn't start with an HTML tag. And even if it does, `find('*')` will ignore the outermost tag, since it only searches descendants. See my answer for the way around these problems.

Comment: @eveo is this what you were looking for then?

Comment: @Barmar I've evaded the problem with the outermost tag by putting the code for the outermost tag seperate below the `$().each`. Also, `$('<b>foo <i>bar</i> baz</b>')` works just fine, so no `<html>` tag needed around it.

Comment: But what if the content of the textarea is `Here is some text in <b>bold</b>`? It doesn't start with a tag, so `$(codeInput)` will fail.

Comment: @Barmar are you even trying these counterexamples? It works just fine. The return for that "counterexample" is `[<b>​bold​</b>]`, so it works just fine. Not sure what you're trying to prove here.

Comment: OK, I hadn't tried it. I thought that since it didn't begin with a tag, it would be treated as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="codeInput">
    <div id="hello"><div class="w"></div></div>
    <div id="world"></div>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
</textarea>
<button id="submitCode">submit</button>

$(function() {
    $('#submitCode').click(function() {
        var CSS_CLASSES = [];
        var CSS_IDS = [];
        var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
        var text = $("#codeInput").val();
        el.innerHTML = text;       
        var nodes = el.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
           var node = nodes[i];
            if(node.id.length > 0) {
              CSS_IDS.push(node.id); 
            }
            if(node.className.length > 0) {
              CSS_CLASSES.push(node.className);    
            }
        }
        console.log(CSS_CLASSES);
        console.log(CSS_IDS);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zeZ93/6/

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what's supposed to be in the textarea. It's not a list of selectors, it's HTML code.

Comment: Read the first line of the question: _a textarea where I paste a block of HTML code_

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like Barmar's solution the best, but this works ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCbN8/5/)):

```
$('#submitCode').click(function() {
   var codeInput = $('#codeInput').val();
   var ids = codeInput.match(/id="(.*?)"/);
   var classes = codeInput.match(/class="(.*?)"/);
   var output = classes[1].split(" ");
   output.push( ids[1] );
   console.log(output);
});
```

Comment: Missing `id=` in the first regexp?

Comment: You're only getting the first ID and class, not all of them.

Comment: @Barmar - I'm learning regex, and would appreciate you looking at my forked question off this answer when you get a chance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326494/using-a-global-pattern-modifier-and-a-lookahead

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitCode').click(function() {
        var ids = [], classes = [];        
        $("[id],[class]").each(function(i, el) {
            var id, c;
            if (id = $(this).attr('id')) {
                ids.push(id);
            }            
            if (c = $(el).attr('class')) {
                classes.push(c);
            }
        });
        console.log(ids, classes);
    });
});
```

Comment: This only gives me the classes and ID's used on the current webpage housing the source code, not the text I paste into the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same challenge and modified the code by @Ryan to extract all (unique) classes and IDs, including when multiple classes are applied to the same element.  It's very useful and works for any URL.

See http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfast/4uftwbm0/57/

Thank you.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<textarea id="codeInput" cols=50 rows=10></textarea>
<button id="submitCode">submit</button>

<!-- jQuery -->

var remoteURL = "https://getbootstrap.com";

function url_content(url) {
  return $.get(url);
}

url_content(remoteURL).success(function(data) {
  $('#codeInput').val(data);
});

$(function() {
  $('#submitCode').click(function() {
    var CSS_CLASSES = [];
    var CSS_IDS = [];
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    var text = $("#codeInput").val();
    el.innerHTML = text;
    var nodes = el.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      var node = nodes[i];
      if (node.id.length > 0) {
        CSS_IDS.push(node.id);
      }
      if (node.className.length > 0) {
        var x = node.className.split(" ")
        $.each(x, function(index, val) {
          if (val != '') {
            CSS_CLASSES.push(val);
          }
        });
      }
    }
    console.log("CLASSES FOUND: ", unique(CSS_CLASSES));
    console.log("IDs FOUND: ", unique(CSS_IDS));
  });
});


function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  return result;
}
```