# Using a global pattern modifier and a lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to understand regex better, so even if there is a different, better solution (which there is), I don't care. I want to solve it with regex.

Specifically when I run the following js/regex:

```
$('#submitCode').click(function() {
    var codeInput = $('#codeInput').val();
    var ids = codeInput.match(/id="(.*?)"/);
    var classes = codeInput.match(/class="(.*?)"/);
    var output = classes[1].split(" ");
    output.push( ids[1] );
    console.log(output);
    });
```

On the following html, with the goal of returning all the ids and css classes inside of `textarea#codeInput`:

```
<textarea id="codeInput">
 <div id="test_id1" class="class1 class2">
  <div id="test_id2" class="class3 class4">test</div>
 </div>
</textarea>
<button id="submitCode">submit</button>
```

It stops after the first match, giving me the following output:

```
["class1", "class2", "test_id1"]
```

After some research, it looks like the global modifier is what I want, but when I add it like so:

```
    var ids = codeInput.match(/id="(.*?)"/g);
    var classes = codeInput.match(/class="(.*?)"/g);
```

This is the output:

```
["class="class3", "class4"", "id="test_id2""]
```

When what I want is:

```
["class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "test_id1", "test_id2"]
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCbN8/5/).

In my research I also started reading more about lookaheads, but I don't see the `(?=)` pattern in my regex, so bonus points to any one who can enlighten me as to what is actually happening in my statement if not a lookahead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a case where I'd take advantage of the ability to use functions to operate on the results of a regex match:

```
var output = [];
codeInput.replace(/(?:class|id)="(.*?)"/g, function(_, values) {
  values.split(" ").forEach(function(s) { output.push(s); });
});
```

The `.replace()` function will call the function you pass it, with the parameters being the match results. The first parameter is the entire matched substring, and the subsequent parameters are the values of the capture groups.

Note that there's no actual replacement going on; the code just takes advantage of that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `g` flag `String.match` does **not** return capturing groups.

So `var ids = codeInput.match(/id="(.*?)"/g);` will return the whole matches:

```
["id="codeInput"", "id="test_id1"", "id="test_id2"", "id="submitCode""]
```

If you want the capturing groups you can call `RegExp.exec` multiple times or use a solution like the one suggested by @Pointy.